# How to get This Year and Last Year from unique table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So, I am trying to get one column for This Year production and another one with Last Year production, and using an calendar table to ensure I have all dates even if I don't have production on some dates.

So I have 2 tables: one with dates (no duplicates) and another one with my production.
So this is my data table:

```
propertyCode    dte         prodCode    unitSold
A               2018-10-01  A10         1
A               2018-10-01  A11         1
A               2019-10-01  A10         1
A               2019-10-01  A11         1
B               2018-10-01  A10         1
B               2018-10-01  A11         1
B               2019-10-01  A10         1
B               2019-10-01  A11         1
```

The below code I am using is giving me duplicates but I don't understand why:

```sql
SELECT SUM(d1.unitSold) sldTY, SUM(d2.unitSold) sldLY
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN data d1 ON d1.propertyCode='A' AND c.dteTY=d1.dte
LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d2.propertyCode='A' AND c.dteLY=d2.dte
WHERE c.dteTY='2019-10-01'
```

See the SQL Fiddle for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e093b/4/0

I should be getting 2 for both this year and last year, but it gives me 4 and I really can't understand why...

Comment: Because first join has two matching rows; and second join also has two matching rows for every matched row found earlier. So it becomes 2*2 = 4 matching rows, and thus duplicates.

Comment: What is the point of the two joins, which seem to have identical join conditions?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they are not. I was confused also; after a close look. Check one field is `dteTy` and another is `dteLy`. difference of T and L

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e093b/14 to make @MadhurBhaiya 's explainment visible what happens when summing on on to many or many to many join results.. Also makes me wonder as INNER JOIN gives the same results that you really need to use LEFT

Comment: *"I should be getting 2 for both this year and last year, but it gives me 4 and I really can't understand why..."* Also after reviewing this data/query does not make anny sense as your are not doing year based filtering of anny kind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the first join has two matching rows; and then, second join also has two matching rows for every matched row found earlier. So it becomes 2*2 = 4 matching rows, and thus duplicates.

Try the following using [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) instead:

```sql
SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(d1.unitSold) 
   FROM data d1 
   WHERE d1.propertyCode = 'A' 
     AND d1.dte = c.dteTY) sldTY, 
  (SELECT SUM(d1.unitSold) 
   FROM data d1 
   WHERE d1.propertyCode = 'A' 
     AND d1.dte = c.dteLY) sldLY
FROM calendar c
WHERE c.dteTY='2019-10-01'
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e093b/15

Comment: @HiPierr0t not sure how i need to look to the topicstarter query or this one as both does not account for *"I should be getting 2 for both this year and last year"* .. it might work for this dataset..   consider -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08a4e3/1 where the years are 2019 and 2017 anyhow the 2017 is not last year when we live in 2019... ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland if there is no record for last year in the `data`, then it should simply return `null` or zero. That is why `LEFT JOIN` existed in the original problem as well

Comment: Don't think you didn't read the comment update as i know how LEFT JOIN works :-)... 2017 is not last year if we live in 2019 annyhow maybe i am reading *"I should be getting 2 for both this year and last year"* to literal in the question.

Comment: @RaymondNijland lol I know that you know ;) But maybe you are over-reading the problem; and OP has most likely given a minimized version of actual query he is trying to do. I think the issue here is due to multiple joins, same row gets duplicated/triplicated etc due to many-to-many/one-to-many joins, and that is why his sum was duplicated/triplicated...

Comment: not over reading, just logical interpreting and not assuming or thinking what the topicstarter might mean with his/her question and example is generally the best as that always avoids making educated geusses :-)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for your explanations! I've managed to achieve the desired result using your approach. This example is a much lighter version of the issue as the query itself is much more complex with plenty of joins and subquerries, so I was trying to make it as short as possible. This works anyway, thanks!